# How to open window with defined path from perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, window-managers

I have a task with these requirements: On Ubuntu 12.04, I need to open an instance of Nautilus (file manager) with a defined path which is set in the Perl script by an user.

Are there any approaches to do it? Thanks for a response.

**UPD**
And is it possible to select a particular file from all files which are located in a folder (path)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is really very vague.  Without anything else to go on:

```
system("nautilus", $path);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's that I need. And do you know how to solve a task which I've added after UPD?

Comment: Just make `$path` a file, instead of a folder.